# How to expose a c++ function that cannot be exposed directly, with the same name

Tags: python, c++, cython

As far as I've understood, it is not possible to expose in python a C++ function that returns a vector[T], because of memory sharing limitations.
Thus, it is necessary to make a second function that uses the imported function and expose it properly to the python extension module.

Problem is: I cannot use the same function name and my extension module ends up with many weirdo function names. Eg. see below, the import of the C++ function, then the expose:

```
cdef extern from "somestuffs.h" namespace "stf":
    cdef vector[float] stufffn(int n)

cpdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] pystufffn(int n):
    return np.asarray(stufffn(n))
```

Is there a way to expose the function stufffn directly without an addhoc function ?
Is there a way to preserve the name "stufffn" in the extension and avoid "pystufffn" ?

Note that I cannot rename the code in somestuffs as I'm building a wrapper for an existing library.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: You can use boost python to expose c++ classes and functions to python.And yes you can return vectors to python from c++ function. Only you have to expose the vector type as well to python module.

Comment: I'm discovering boost python right now, looks great.
Would you have any pointer/reference/example for your last two sentences?

Comment: See also pybind11, essentially a "modern" (taking advantage of c++11) version of Boost.Python https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Comment: pybind11 is The easy way to do this wraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, from the doc-link below, is declare your extern functions in a `pxd` file, and use it with a namespace so you can re-use the name in your implementation.

```
# wrappers.pxd
cdef extern from "somestuffs.h" namespace "stf":
    cdef vector[float] stufffn(int n)

# mymodule.pyx
cimport wrappers
cpdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] stufffn(int n):
    return np.asarray(wrappers.stufffn(n))
```

http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#using-cimport-to-resolve-naming-conflicts